# Reinit on @Input change

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

Is it possible to tell angular to run the init (or any other lifecycle function or function) when the component input changes or I have to call that function from the parent component instead of changing the input?

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When component's input changes, `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook runs. There you can call any other `lifecycle hook or/and any function` as you want.

```
ngOnChanges(...args: any[]) {

    console.log('onChange fired');            
    this.ngOnInit();
}

ngOnInit()
{
    console.log('ngOnInit fired');
}
```

**EDIT**: 
for some reason, if you want to call child's `ngOnInit` from parent then you can make use of `ViewChild` as shown below.

```
export class Parent{

   @ViewChild(child) vc:child;

    ngAfterViewInit()
    { 
      console.log("ngAfterInit");
      console.log(this.vc.ngOnInit());
    }

};

export class child{

   ngOnInit()
    {
        console.log('ngOnInit fired');
    }
};
```