# How to safely load/initialize the same child components repeatedly

Tags: javascript, angular

This is an architectural question related to Angular 4 and how best to initialize data given how angular loads child components.

Scenario:
I have a parent component with a data table and when any row in the table is clicked it opens one of 3 child components (in a sidebar view) depending on whether you want add a new item to the table, edit the selected row, or view details about it (basic CRUD functionality). IOTW, the user may invoke the same 3 components repeatedly as they work with data table in parent component.

By design in angular, the child components only run OnInit lifecycle events the first time the component is utilized. So for example, if if i edit row 1, the 'edit' child component runs it's onInit hook, however, if I subsequently edit row 2, onInit in the edit component won't run, since that component has already loaded according to angular.

In order to be able to initialize the data in the child components *each and every time* the user wants to do something like edit a newly selected row (parent data table operation), I'm using onChanges lifecycle hook in the child component.

The problem:
I suspect this approach of initializing data via onChanges is an anti-pattern since onChanges runs repeatedly in the child components, forcing me to be wary on what initialization code I can put in there.

Question:
Is there a better way to load the child components that will allow me to reliably initialize them *only once* each and every time they are triggered by the parent component?

Thank you,

S. Arora

Comment: Not sure how your child component is initialized (dynamically?), depending on how it is done, you could probably use `NgZone`

Comment: Each of the child components has an *ngIf to determine whether it ought to display, and a 'selectedRow' input. When the user triggers the 'edit' button on a particular row in the parent component's data table, the edit component runs onInit (first time a user clicks edit only) and ngOnChanges (anytime selectedRow' input variable changes, OR I guess any other input / output variables change on the child component).

Comment: I'm researching your suggestion on ngZone, as well as other options like forcing onInit to re-run (detailed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36513241/reinit-on-input-change). One consideration in picking a solution is that i'm currently relying on change detection to pass the selectedRow input variable to the child component, and that input always needs to be passed before the child component's initialization code re-runs. As long as a forced approach respects ngOnChange cycle running first I guess it could work. Will try.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the option of forcing onInit to re-run as a way to safely initialize when need but unfortunately it runs before the input variable is received, so it doesn't have what it needs to initialize.

Taking a step back, I think I'm trying to solve the wrong problem here..I believe I need to rely on angular's standard way of passing data via Input paramater and leveraging ngOnChanges to re-initialize the child component based on the new Input variable.

The real pitfall I encountered is what I referred to when I said "onChanges runs repeatedly in the child components"..its what was throwing me off and is detailed here along with workarounds: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7782

So on component load the one-time sequence is: 1) run onChanges (input variable is null) 2) run onInit 3) run onChanges (input variable is latest).

Subsequently the sequence is simply to run onChanges once when the input variable changes, so if you can ignore the first null param on step #1 no biggie.

HOWEVER, not only does onChanges run twice when a child component is loaded, but it repeats the described 1-2-3 sequence if you alternate child components to display as in my scenario where the user can alternate between loading edit / view child components for a given data row they select in a data table.

To boot, on step #1 I noticed angular will pass a stale Input param when onChanges runs, before passing the latest Input param on step #3.

If your child component has idempotent initialization code you might never notice all this, but in my case step #1 and #3 were firing in quick succession and triggering Observable subscriptions that were not idempotent...(not fun to debug!).

Unless / until the design flaw in angular is addressed, I imagine this pitfall will remain. Hope this helps...